# Eliminating $x$, $y$, $z$ from $\frac{x^2-xy-xz}{a}=\frac{y^2-yx-yz}{b}=\frac{z^2-zx-zy}{c}$ and $ax+by+cz=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Here is a Math Tripos problem I cannot solve.

> Eliminate $x$, $y$, $z$ from the equations
> $$\frac{x^2-xy-xz}{a}=\frac{y^2-yx-yz}{b}=\frac{z^2-zx-zy}{c}$$ and
> $$ax+by+cz=0$$

I dont know if there is a general (practical) method for such problem. I think you just manipulate the equations to eliminate $x,y,z$ but have been unable to find the path in this question.

The answer is $a^3+b^3+c^3=a^2(b+c)+b^2(a+c)+c^2(a+b)$ if that yields any insight.

Comment: What year was it? and What part of the Tripos?

Comment: @almagest Sorry I dont know that. The question is from an old text and is attributed to Math Tripos.

Comment: It's just that if it was an old (say pre-1920) Part II Q, it could be quite difficult and I don't want to waste time tangling wth it!

Comment: Its at least pre 1891. What you dont like a challenge ? Anyway I dont think those old problems are THAT hard, they just have a different set of tricks.

Comment: Sure. I spent a happy day or two in Trinity's Wren Library digging out old Part II Math Tripos Qs and seeing how hard they were. But remember that in the old Tripos system the Senior Wrangler got umpteen times more marks than the number 50 guy in the order of merit. It is a question of practice. The IMO Qs are dramatically harder now than when I did them in 1968. Back then most people walked out after 1-2 hours. But I find the current IMO Qs quite hard (partly because I only look at such things for 10 mins a year).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's denote $t$ be equal to

$$t = \frac{x^2-xy-xz}{a}=\frac{y^2-yx-yz}{b}=\frac{z^2-zx-zy}{c}$$

We have:
\begin{align}
t &=\frac{(y^2-yx-yz)+(z^2-zx-zy)-(x^2-xy-xz)}{b+c-a} \\
  &=\frac{(y^2-2yz+z^2)-x^2}{b+c-a} \\
 &=\frac{(y-z)^2-x^2}{b+c-a} \\
  &=-\frac{(z+x-y)(x+y-z)}{b+c-a} \\
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
t^2 &=-\frac{(z+x-y)(x+y-z)}{b+c-a} \times \frac{x^2-xy-xz}{a} \\
    &=-\frac{(z+x-y)(x+y-z)}{b+c-a} \times \frac{-x(y+z-x)}{a} \\
&=(x+y-z)(y+z-x)(z+x-y) \times \frac{x}{a(b+c-a)} \\
\end{align}

We have then
$$\frac{a(b+c-a)}{x} = \frac{b(c+a-b)}{y} = \frac{c(a+b-c)}{z}  = u $$
$$\left(\text{both equal to  } u =\frac{(x+y-z)(y+z-x)(z+x-y)}{t^2} \right)$$

We can deduce that
$$u = \frac{a^2(b+c-a)}{ax} = \frac{b^2(c+a-b)}{by} = \frac{c^2(a+b-c)}{cz} $$
Hence:
$$a^2(b+c-a)+b^2(c+a-b)+c^2(a+b-c) = u(ax+by+cz) = 0$$
(because $ax +by +cz = 0$)

Finally, we can conclude that
$$a^2(b+c)+b^2(c+a)+c^2(a+b) = a^3 + b^3+c^3$$

Comment: Wow great solution ! I wasnt thinking along these lines at all. But I think this is the right way.

Comment: From the first equations $\frac{x^2-xy-xz}{a}=\frac{y^2-yx-yz}{b}=...$ I found out that $x^3+y^3+z^3 = x^2(y+z)+y^2(z+x)+z^2(x+y)$. So, I thought the $(x,y,z)$ and $(a,b,c)$ must have similar role. Hence, I tried to prove $\frac{a(b+c-a)}{x} = \frac{b(c+a-b)}{y} = \frac{c(a+b-c)}{z}$.

Comment: Yeah, I like the symmetry of the reversal.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a computational problem. It can be routinely solved in SageMath using elimination in polynomial rings.
Here is a [sample code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFj7sOwjAMRfd-hcekNQExMAFbpy60a1WQG0IVKU2kUqQkX0_KQ2JjsaxjH_m6EXuPASMS9iiPcICTM8G6UZNptB1YXeOOZ1UaNEJfFRkGrX2MaqLZTYz58xZW4PPwqpGvKTUs_NCw0J4j_LXih8avJZNFuYcC-rRagMxjBzwrU5hKKKNHbWnWzl7ewdr0ScezG8nlSCkGZe-Mt5uOPwEdzULB&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) to run.

Notice that since we are given just 3 equations (i.e. generators of the original ideal), we cannot request elimination of $x,y,z$ altogether (as this would yield zero ideal), but luckily elimination of $x,y$ results in the ideal generated by $z^3$ times a polynomial in $a,b,c$ -- this polynomial is what we need.

---

Alternatively, elimination can be done using [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant). Here is a [sample code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyVjEEKwyAQRfeeYpZqpyl00VXbMzQ5QGGUaALGgDWgnr4KKWTbzefzZv4bunvCjAUJFeonPOC1uuzXZSY3zN7yvsebYKYeSCY4gZK5ppaF2cpMF8bP5iL5yMFvyxgoroHz9L7CGVL9bVnEhWrh-UBzo0ogJBBs-ltVdlp-Kr2rDOk2A3vQTZgFiC-f0URJ&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) to run.